# LoopBack: Setting Required Fields at a Later Time

Tags: json, node.js, dependencies, loopbackjs, required

I have come across a scenario where I want the 'email' property to be required if 'type' value is 'online'. In a generic point a view I have a field that may be required or not depending on another fields value. How would I go about solving this scenario?

```
"properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
      "required": //true or false depending on what 'type' is
    }
  }
```

Comment: I updated my code to also accept partial update of potential multiple models. That way you're safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare all potentially not required field as non-required, and use an [operation hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) `before save` to validate the fields in function of your custom logic.

Inside your model.js file, implement the hook with the logic you need. For instance if type is 'A' and requires an email but there is none provided in the request, generate an error and call `next(err)`. This way, the request will be denied.

```
MyModel.observe('before create', function(ctx, next) {
    if(ctx.instance){
        data = ctx.instance
    } else {
        data = ctx.data
    {
    if(data.type =='A' && !data.email){
        next(new Error('No email provided !')
    } else {
       next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up@overdriver's code to make it more implementable

```
  MyModel.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    let obj = ctx.instance;

    if(obj.type == 'A' && obj.email == null){
        next(new Error('No email provided !'));
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
  });
```

Comment: taken your feedback into account. Thanks.